# Remotely accessible hostname for WCF TCP binding endpoint

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding

A local endpoint defined as `net.tcp://localhost:<port>/MyRemoteApp` can only be accessed from the local system.

- Which hostname or IP should I use to ensure that the WCF service is accessible from all remote network interfaces?
- What is the most compatible way to retrieve such a name?
- Or do I need multiple endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 0.0.0.0: and service will bind to all interfaces on the current machine.